# How to grab output from command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, output

I'm trying to write a shell script in RHEL which will execute `grub-md5-crypt` and the user will type their password.

Now the problem is how can I grab the encrypted md5 hash displayed to the user in the shell script?

I tried to figure this out but command redirection will not work here. 
So how can I get the md5 encrypted text in the shell script after the script has executed `grub-md5-crypt`?

Answer (score 10):

```
result=$(grub-md5-crypt | grep xy)
echo $result
```

If grub-md5-crypt prints to stderr use:

```
result=$(grub-md5-crypt 2>&1 | grep xy)
echo $result
```

Comment: It workes if I directly execute it in the shell. But not in my shell script.

Comment: @Tarun This works in all shells. If it doesn't work for you, you made some other mistake, or you have an unrelated problem. Ask a new question if you can't figure it out, and be sure to post your code and say how it doesn't work (do you get errors, what happens, etc.).

Comment: thank you for mentioning `2>&1` for getting result from stderr

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't work in your shell script you might want to use bash.
Just add:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It **must** be in the **first** line of your file!

This means your script will be using bash interpreter other than normal shell's one (`/bin/sh`).

Completing *noEntry*'s answer, you can also save output to a file.

```
grub-md5-crypt | grep xy > output
```

Or:

```
result=$(grub-md5-crypt 2>&1 | grep xy)
echo $result > output
```

This will generate a file names output with whatever would have been printed on screen.